# Connection reset when connecting to nodejs https server

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, server

So I'm trying to get a basic https server running in node, and I'm completely stuck. I've generated a self signed certificate and key with openssl, and tried the basic way to create the server and another hundred of them, but no matter what I do my browser just tells me "The connection has been reset" when I try to connect, and the server doesn't even execute the callback function for the request, as if it has never arrived.

The network inspector in Firefox Developer Edition shows no response at all from the server, and inspecting my loopback interface using Wireshark I've found the server is sending an "end" package right after acknowledging the browser's request.

I really have no idea on what can be wrong, as I've tried with example codes from many tutorials and all of them produce the same output.

This is an example of some very basic code that throws no errors, but also apparently doesn't work:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('sslcert/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.crt'),
    rejectUnauthorized: false
}
https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
    console.log('request received')
    res.writeHead(200)
    res.end('hello')
}).listen(8443).on('error', (error) => {
    throw error
})
```

Comment: Also check out 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54836702/redirect-from-http-to-https-using-node-js-express
to learn how to create a simple HTTP to HTTPS redirect in Node.js

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem, and for me, accessing the page with the https:// -protocol specified did the job in Firefox.

So use
https://localhost:8443
instead of just
http://localhost:8443

Comment: This is correct! If just you were here 7 months ago :P

Comment: Saved me after 24 hours of searching and trying different solutions!

Comment: How do I resolve this on localhost? Localhost uses http.